# How to activate FAST_ASSERT mode in Optapy

Tags: optaplanner, optapy

First, thanks to work on a Python version of OptaPlanner. I thinks it's a great idea. I have encountered a problem. I have a SolverConfig objectif in Optapy and I want to activate the FAST_ASSERT mode without passing by the XML file but I can't find a way. Does anyone know how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like OptaPlanner, you can configure all of OptaPy programmatically. All configuration classes can be found in the `optapy.config` module (which shares the same structure as the `org.optaplanner.core.config` Java package). As for your particular question, this is how you can configure the enviroment mode programmatically in OptaPy:

```
import optapy.config

solver_config = optapy.config.solver.SolverConfig() \
    .withEnvironmentMode(optapy.config.solver.EnvironmentMode.FAST_ASSERT) \
    .withSolutionClass(Solution) \
    .withEntityClasses(Entity) \
    .withConstraintProviderClass(my_constraints)
```